# Rewrite order of $\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{y}} \int_y^1 \, dz \, dx \, dy$ to $dx\,dy\,dz$ and $dy\,dz\,dx$

Tags: integration, integral-inequality

I need to change the order of $$\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{y}}\int_y^1\,dz\,dx\,dy$$ to $dx\,dy\,dz$ and $dy\,dz\,dx.$

I can extract the inequalities to get $1≤z≤y$, $0≤x≤\sqrt y$, $0≤y≤1$, but I get confused when it comes to rewriting the bounds.

I know that I start with the outermost bound, so take $dx\,dy\,dz$, I think $0≤z≤1$. I'm not sure if that's right, but that's what I think I get when I take the smallest possible lowest bound the the largest possible upperbound. Then I don't know how to continue

Comment: Draw the region, it really helps.  The inner most integral limits are functions of the last two variables, the middle integral's limits are functions of the last variable, and the outer most integral limits are constants.  It also helps to write out which variable goes to which limit; ie $$\int_{y=0}^{y=1} \int_{x=0y+0}^{x=\sqrt{y}} \int_{z=0x+y+0}^{z=0x+0y+1} dz dx dy$$

Comment: You mistyped the inequalities, that are actually $$y\leqslant z\leqslant 1\quad0\leqslant x\leqslant\sqrt y\quad0\leqslant y\leqslant 1$$ which can be rewritten as the single sequence of inequalities $$0\leqslant x\leqslant\sqrt{y}\leqslant\sqrt{z}\leqslant1$$ from which the answer to your question should be direct. To integrate in the order $dxdydz$ for example, use $$0\leqslant x\leqslant\sqrt{y}\quad 0\leqslant y\leqslant z\quad 0\leqslant z\leqslant1$$ Likewise, for the order $dydzdx$, use $$x^2\leqslant y\leqslant z\quad x^2\leqslant z\leqslant 1\quad 0\leqslant x\leqslant1$$

Comment: Thus, one will get the integrals $$\int_0^1\int_0^z\int_0^{\sqrt{y}}\cdots\, dx\,dy\,dz$$ and $$\int_0^1\int_{x^2}^1\int_{x^2}^z\cdots\, dy\,dz\,dx$$ respectively.

Comment: @Did: The problem with answers given as comments is that users will consider the question as answered and no longer post answers, and this leaves the post on the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: @AlexM. On the other hand, the OP can start from these sketchy indications and develop them into a full answer of their own, whose validity the community can then check, for the happiness and enlightement of all... (Note for example that even the alleged typo has yet to be confirmed.)